# Will java script work on android application?

Tags: java, javascript, android, payment, credit-card

I have an html page which has a payment form.When we type the credit card number ,  a javascript caputures the credit card number and convert it to a cypher text.This cypher text using php is posted to a webservice using cUrl.The webservice returns a token which we can use as credit card number.Since i dont have PCI compliance i cant store Credit card number as is,so can be stored as token only.

So what I am trying to do is make an android application equalent to this web application.But the credit card tokenizastion part,using javascript.How can I make it possible?instead of that javascript(provided by the tokenizing company),what can be used?Is it possible to use javascript in my android application?

Pardon me for this kind of a question.

Comment: You could use `ScriptEngine`, or you could use the Browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), You can run html+js+css as an application

Comment: As an application or with in an application?Im creating an application similar to paytm,which has a payment form.Can I do this inside an application?

Comment: as an application... you can build with phoneGap (or may I call it "Cordova") mobile application.. If you already have an application and you only want to add this html page , so You need to edit your question and explain it better.

Look here: http://phonegap.com/app/

Answer (score 0):

> I have an html page which has a payment form.When we type the credit card number , a javascript caputures the credit card number and convert it to a cypher text.

From your question I get the strong impression that you have no idea what you're doing and shouldn't be processing credit card numbers in any way.

You can't merely use Javascript to encrypt credit card numbers - if you could, SSL would be obsolete. If you use SSL you don't need to double-encrypt it for transmission.

Moreover, please refer to [this](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/tokenization), which says:

> To be PCI compliant, merchants must install expensive end-to-end encryption systems or outsource their payment processing to a service provider who provides a "tokenization option."

and [this](http://www.mijireh.com/docs/what-you-need-to-know-about-pci-compliance/), which says:

> Do I Need To Worry About PCI Compliance?
>
> Anyone who has a business that receives payments from customers who use their credit cards to pay needs to be PCI compliant – even if you only receive one credit card payment per year. The volume of transactions does not make a difference. Even if your website uses a 3rd party service like PayPal, Google Checkout, or Mijireh you still need to be PCI compliant because your business (not necessarily your website) receives payments via credit card.

**So, you are mistaken if you think you don't need to be PCI compliant. Tokenization is a way to achieve PCI compliance more easily, not a way to avoid it entirely.**

Comment: Normally a one who dont have pci comliance cant process or store a credi card number.So there are third party tokenising companies which tokenises the card number  which we can process and store!and I know what I am doing fyi!

Comment: So what's the purpose of the cypher text? I can't think what it could be.

Comment: this cypher text is sent to third party web service (tokenisingcompany) which convert the cypher into a token,which will be sent back to us.And note,the javascript is provided by them(tokenising company). For more info you may check www.tokenex.com

Comment: suggest you contact them directly as you are a customer of theirs, surely they have someone you can call

Comment: Yes anyway I got the solution.Its better to use phonegap anyway

Comment: well i havnt told,im avoiding pci compliance.Just that I cant afford I use a third party tokenizing comany.You are imagining things by your own I guess

Comment: No no no! You are in serious danger of violating PCI compliance because you are clueless! Please listen to me!

Comment: I dont under stand what you are saying

Comment: SSL is used to encrypt credit card numbers over the internet. People who do not use SSL properly for sending credit card numbers over the internet, face having their entire businesses ruined, made bankrupt, by violating PCI compliance. If you are using SSL properly, there is no need to re-encrypt the credit card number, because SSL already encrypts it - unless you are storing the credit card number, which you explicitly said you _aren't_ doing.

Comment: Yes I use ssl.I have SSL certificate and it is mandatory for tokenizing purpose.Without pci compliance you cant play with someones credit card number.So tokenising it will make it secure.

Comment: I dont think,you will understand this.I have a clear picture on what I am doing.PCI security standard council suggests this

Comment: You're using SSL! Great! I suggest you contact your tokenization provider, because it sounds like they're using some nonsensical extra layer of security that doesn't actually provide any extra security. So this is a problem of their creation. Either way, I'm sure they can advise you on the best way to do this while remaining PCI compliant.